# Access Sibling Object from Function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to access an object (`childObject1`) which is a sibling object to the function (`childObject2`). Although this is the case, it appears as though the function cannot access `childObject1` but it can access fields within it such as `grandChildObject1`.

```
parentObject: {
    childObject1: "Child Object 1",
    childObject2: function() {
          var grandChildObject1 = "Grandchild Object 1";
          console.log(childObject1);
          console.log(grandChildObject1)
    }
}
```

The first log prints:

> undefined

The second log prints:

> Grandchild Object 1

Why is the function not able to access the value of `childObject1` if they are siblings?

Comment: `childObject1` is not a variable. Its a property defined on the `parentObject` whereas `grandChildObject1` is a variable defined in local scope. To access the property you have access it through the object where the property was defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `this`:

```js
var parentObject = {
    childObject1: "Child Object 1",
    childObject2: function() {
          var grandChildObject1 = "Grandchild Object 1";
          console.log(this.childObject1);
          console.log(grandChildObject1);
    }
};

parentObject.childObject2();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately that still produces "undefined"

Comment: Try running the snippet that I just added. It is working there :p

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `this`. change

```
console.log(childObject1);
```

to

```
console.log(this.childObject1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Much like any other static methods, you would have to go though the parent object e.g. parentObject1.childObject1 when accessing it from childObject2. There is no instance of a static object hence they are not really logical siblings.

Comment: But is there any way to get parentObject1 as you describe?

Comment: Yes, you can console.log(this.childObject1); as mentioned on the answer or console.log(parentObject.childObject1); from inside your childObject 2 and they should provide the same result.